# Python flask blueprint ImportError: cannot import name 'bp'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, import, attributeerror, blueprint

I am trying to get my login page working with blueprints. Before I separated my python package into separate packages, the app was successfully running with just app.py. However, now I am trying to make it more modular, I am having trouble running the app and it does not let me import the `blueprint` I created.

My file structure is like this:

```
myapp/
run.py
myapp/
    __init.py__
    app.py
    models.py
...
```

Here is my `run.py`:

```
from myapp import app
app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I am initializing my blueprint in `app.py` like this:

```
.... 
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
@bp.route('/home')
....
```

I am calling it from `__init.py__` like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
....
app.config...
app.config...
app.config...
....

from . import bp             # line 35
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

However, no matter what I change the import to, it keeps complaining that it cannot import

```
# python3 run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from usb import app
  File "/my/path/to/myapp/myapp/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import bp
ImportError: cannot import name 'bp'
```

I even tried changing `from . import bp` to `from myapp.app import bp`, and then it throws a different error `AttributeError: module 'myapp.app' has no attribute 'register_blueprint'`

Here is the full error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from myapp import app
  File "/my/path/to/myapp/myapp/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
AttributeError: module 'myapp.app' has no attribute 'register_blueprint'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you should export the bp which was in app.py, I guess the bp was a private variable. I am not sure, you can try.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you need to replace from `from . import bp` to
`from myapp.app import bp`.
This happens because of `__init__.py`, which makes package from 'myapp' dir, and python wait import path with package name.

Here is a little exmaple:
Project Structure:

```
myapp\
  myapp\
    __init__.py
    app.py
  run.py
```

`run.py` listing:

```
from myapp import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

`myapp\__init__.py` listing:

```
from flask import Flask
from myapp.app import bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

`myapp\app.py` listing:

```
from flask import Blueprint

@bp.route('/')
@bp.route('/home')
def home():
   return '<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>'
```

Comment: In my post, I did indicate, that I tried changing it `from . import bp` to `from myapp.app import bp`, but after changing it I get this error `AttributeError: module 'myapp.app' has no attribute 'register_blueprint'`. Have you seen this before? (i updated the full error output when i tried what you suggested in my post)

Comment: So I renamed my files and changed my files structure a bit and all of a sudden it started working. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Yes, I have seen your comment, but I have no enough repatation to comment. What kind of changes you made to solve your problem?

Comment: I changed two things, first I changed `my_app` folder name it used to be called just `app`, and then I changed `app.py` to `auth.py` and put it in an auth directory. Not sure which step fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had something similar happening. It was a rookie mistake of creating a folder with the same name as a library and importing it. Whoops.

Folder structure:

```bash
.
├── main.py
├── numpy # this name here is the problem
│   └── __init__.py
└── routes
    └── index.py
```

The `index.py` file uses the actual `numpy` library, importing it as follows `import numpy as np`, which was throwing the error.

I simply had to rename the `numpy` directory to something else that does not correspond to a library name.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs because you are calling the bp instance without first loading it. When the python interpreter tries to load the route, for example:

```
# app/catalog/routes.py
from app.catalog import bp

@bp.route('/')
def hello():
   return "hello world"
```

and verifies that the bp instance has not yet been loaded, it returns the error, describing that it has not found the bp module.

so to resolve this, in the blueprint configuration file, it will be mandatory to call the route after registering the blueprint. example:

```
# app/catalog/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint
bp = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates')
from app.catalog import routes
```